# SQL select column equivalence

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table that saves the possible states of other tables (entities).
But now I need to find equivalence of states between two entities.
The table structure is something like this

```
ID   TableID   StateValue   StateDefinition  StateDescription
================================================================
1    1         1            Created          Just created
2    1         2            Dropped          Just Dropped
3    2         1            Created          Just Created
4    2         2            Aproved          Passed the revision
5    2         3            Dropped          Just dropped
```

I want to get equivalent (comparing text of state) which as a result get this:

```
   TableID1     StateValue1       TableID2       StateValue2    StateDefinition
   =============================================================================
   1            1                 2              1              Created
   1            2                 2              3              Dropped
```

My question is, how can it be done??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select t1.TableID as TableID1,
    t1.StateValue as StateValue1,
    t2.TableID as TableID2,
    t2.StateValue as StateValue2,
    t1.StateDefinition  
from MyTable t1
inner join MyTable t2 on t1.TableID = 1 and t2.TableID = 2
where t1.StateValue = t2.StateValue 
    and t1.StateDefinition  = t2.StateDefinition
```

Comment: The fixed `t1.TableID = 1` and `t2.TableID = 2` parts do not generalize well.

Comment: Does this actually return the result that the OP asked about? The t1.StateValue = t2.Statevalue join would mean that the second row in his resultset is not returned..

Comment: @NWest You are right, I hadn't noticed that. I think the `WHERE` clause should actually be: `where t1.StateDefinition = t2.StateDefinition`. I took *"equivalence of states"* to mean that they would be equal.

Answer (score 3):

Do a self join on the table.

A general case might look like:

```
SELECT A.TableID as TableId1, 
       A.StateValue as StateValue1, 
       B.TableId as TableId2, 
       B.StateValue as StateValue2,
       A.StateDefinition
FROM
  Table A 
INNER JOIN Table B 
  ON (A.TableId <> B.TableId and A.StateDefiniton = B.StateDefinition)
```